# Java: Getting the array location of null values

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, null

So...the program I am trying to create in Java is a simulator that moves different types of creatures around through the use of lists and a 2D array. Currently before each creature tries to move it does a search of the surrounding tiles to see what is there, and reacts differently depending on what it finds, e.g. a predator or food creature. My challenge is if it finds nothing I need some way of knowing the array index position of empty elements/spaces around it so I can randomly move to one of those spaces. Posting some code below to hopefully make more sense:

```
ArrayList <Fish> fishes; ArrayList <Penguin> penguins; ArrayList <Shark> sharks;
```

These are the different types of creature objects stored in arraylist when they are created, each type is a child/extends of the Creature class. New creatures are made in the init method (along with lists and arrays initialised) and then defined in the createNew method, which each creature type has. Once this is done it added one of the above lists and 2 other places:

```
ArrayList<Creature> crlist; Creature [][] gridloc;
```

crlist is a list of all creatures currently alive in the simulator and gridloc is each creature's position in relation to each other and the screen, and is the most important one for them knowing where to move to.

When a creature moves it uses the move method, which first does this:

```
List<Creature> moves = search();
```

and search does this...

```
public ArrayList<Creature> search() {

        int gx = getPos().width/txs; int gy = getPos().height/tys;
        search = new ArrayList();

        for (int sy=-1;sy<=1;sy++) {
           for (int sx=-1;sx<=1;sx++) {
               if (gridloc[gx+sx][gy+sy]!=this && gx+sx>=0 && gx+sx<=ntx && gy+sy>=0 && gy+sy<=nty) {
                   search.add(gridloc[gx+sx][gy+sy]);
               }
           }
        }

        return search;
    }
```

This simply searches all the array indexes/tiles around the creature, while ignoring itself and making sure it can't search past the edge of the window. The results of search are then modified in the child method depending on the creature types (above is called with super.search()) with a priority depending on what it finds as described at the start, so if it finds a predator it will remove anything but a null value/empty space from the search list so it can try and run away.

My challenge is (after that long winded explanation) within move it gets a modified version of the search list to determin where the creature can move to. However as empty spaces contain null values I cant think of a way gettin the position/index of these spaces for the creatures to move to.
The only idea I did have was when search found a null value to add to the list, it could create a new object, which just holds coordinates that the move method can use. Just hoping there is a better way...?

Comment: I actually thinks that the list with coordinates is pretty good idea

Comment: what if each creature had its own x,y instead?

Comment: @LarsNielsen, Yep I may have to go with that idea, although I have sort of already tried it by adding an object of the Creature class when it finds a null value. However the problem was trying to refine the list to only contain those objects it returned other creatures it found too as they are also considered objects of Creature even thought they are child classes.

Comment: @Leo Creatures do have their own x and y position :) It is set when they are created and moved by a pair of get/set methods called getPos & setPos. This however is set as a Dimension and relates to their x,y position on the screen not their position on gridloc sadly. However where I declare gx and gy is the objects gridloc position as txs/tys is the fixed size of each tile stored in: `Dimension [][] xyco`

Comment: @JocelynWilde sorry it was a silly question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about returning a wrapper object.

```
enum Type{
    Food, Null, Predator
}

class Wrapper{
    Creature c;
    int x,y;
    Type positionType;
}

public ArrayList<Wrapper> search(){}
```

You might also have `search` return a `Multimap<Type, Wrapper>` so that you can quickly check for a neighboring predator or food without iterating the list.

[Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: Multimap....is not something I have used before (still learning Java)...will look into it to see if I can understand how it works tho :) The Wrapper idea seems interesting though...just not sure how to implement it yet. Does also seem a maybe better way of determining what creature types are found in the search.

Comment: `Multimap` is basically a `Map<Key, List<Value>>`. If you are not that familiar with Maps, you might want to stick with the List and just do a search for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `NullCreature` and use it for all empty grid locations. If you "preload" these into the grid, your `search()` method doesn't need to create them (just add them to the return list).

Or **preferable** return a wrapper object which holds a `Creature` list (your current return value) and a list of empty positions. This is better imo because what you really want to do is return more information than just the list of nearby creatures.

Comment: I would rather not fill the entire gridloc array with objects though, as it shouldnt be needed since half the time those elements/objects wont be used. It is just the null/empty values around each creature I need to be able to tell the coordinates of. I guess a wrapper class would be better and more efficient than creating a whole new child class of Creature for empty space objects though...